# Show flash message from server.js to html in particular div with id

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I get an error message from server.js and it gets display using 'connect-flash' but it gets redirected with blank page. I want to show the message on same page in a specific div with id in html.
Here is my server.js code

```
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    // var username = req.body.
    if (global.debugMode) debugger;
    console.log("userLogin.html".grey);
    var loginmsg = req.flash('error');
    if(loginmsg.length>0){
        console.log(loginmsg);
        res.send('<h3>'+loginmsg+'</h3>');
    }
    res.sendFile(`${path.dirname(__dirname)}//public/Login/userLogin.html`);
});
```

I want to show 'loginmsg' in specific div on same page but it disaplay on blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comme from express understanding i think. You get a blank page with your flash message in a `<h3>` ? It's because you do a `res.send` when you have a flash message. We can only send one response for one request (https://www.webnots.com/what-is-http/), or here you try to send first the `h3` then send your html file. It's not the good way to do such things.

## First solution

With your solution, the only way to do what you whant is to build the html string dynamically :

```
var myHtml = `<html><head>...</head><body>`

if(loginmsg.length > 0) { myHtml += `<h3>${loginmsg}</h3>` }

myHtml += `rest of my page ...`
myHtml += `</body></html>`

res.send(myHtml)
```

But it's clearly no the good practice to do this.

## Good practice

Use templates ! (http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html). With template you can build an html page with dynamic values in it, like your flash message ! With ejs template (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) you will have a `.ejs` file template like that :

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <% if (loginmsg) { %>
      <h3><%= loginmsg %></h3>
    <% } %>

    Rest of my page...
</body>
</html>
```

And in your express app :

```
 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var loginmsg = req.flash('error');
    ...
    res.render('myTemplate', { loginmsg });
});
```

Have fun ✌️

Comment: I tried using .ejs file but when the browser loads the file it directly downloads the page.

Comment: You must configure your application to work with ejs, please see some courses like this one https://medium.com/@Linda_Ikechukwu/https-medium-com-linda-ikechukwu-using-ejs-as-a-template-engine-in-your-express-app-cb3d82c15e17